# How to convert a flash game (AS2) to android?

Tags: android, flash, apk, actionscript-2

I've made a game in *AS2* which is basically only controlled with a left mouse click. Is it possible to publish it to Android? The code I used for the click is:

```
if (Key.isDown(1)) {
do something
}
```

I tried googling, but no luck...

Comment: Simply put, "No" .. Android apps must be made in Java.  I hope it's not another Flappy Bird clone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert your AS2 game code to AS3 game code. This article ( http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html ) talks in detail about the migration from AS2 to AS3
2. After migration, you need to use Adobe AIR to build your AS3 game for android

So, in short, yes you can make your game for android albeit you need to take a detour :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am some what new to programming, but I have to say I disagree with you sdj I have published and played games using using as3 in adobe flash cs6. The publish setting include air for android as3. as far as as2 I have not found a way because air android only supports as3 in flash cs6.